# Trigger jquery function after php form submitted (not ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, triggers

I have a form submit via php and after submitted which mean data inserted to the db and 
I want to trigger a jquery function automatically and the function contain the inserted data.

Problem I facing is during the page load, the jquery.js file has not load yet and I can't call 
the jquery function.

Another problem, If after the page loaded, how can I automatic trigger the jquery function?

Comment: Is it the page that *receives* the form data the one who triggers the function or is it the page that *submits* the form data?

Answer (score 0):

Add the script tag that includes the `jQuery` in head before your use `jQuery` and put your `javascript` just before ending body tag. Putting the code in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) will ensure the availability of DOM elements to your script and trigger the javascript as the page is ready after being accessed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //your code here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
this will trigger on form submit

```
$('.formclass').on('submit',function(){

    // this will redirect to the page you want 
    window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";

 });
```

but if you want to trigger a function when the form is submitted and the new page is loaded then @Adil suggestion is what you need ..

but you have to be sure that this page only shows after the form submit if for example after submitting the form you redirect to the home page and you used the document.ready then this will run when the page is loaded regardless of the form submit-ion , so every time i go to the main page it will fire  ...

Comment: You just pointed out what i wanted to say. Yes, I want to trigger after the submitted because i want to make sure the data is inserted to db. Second, I want it to redirect back to the home page. is it possible?

Comment: if so then my solution is what you need ... i will edit the answer just a sec.

Comment: So with your code the jquery function is triggered after the php forum submitted?

Comment: How about the inserted data?    will it pass to the jquery function?
Including the autoincrement ID

Comment: Oh no, Ajax. I knew it. Just because I haven't implement the ajax file upload. Thanks anyway.